# Sentry logged exception without additional data

Tags: python, sentry, raven

Sentry 6.4.4

Python raven 5.0.0

Integration with Django 1.7.0.

When I try to store 500 error (automation raven handling), I get in Sentry empty event, without any additional information.

It stored only exception name and time.

But this should be request information, additional info, etc.

I checked my project configuration with http://getsentry.com - in this site all works fine, so problem with my Sentry installation.

But I can't find any information what I should set up to store this data, it seems like this should works from box. But not in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with cache.

Solution is set projects settings:

CACHES = None